# Fixed points and their stability on a non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, fixed-points, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm modelling the spread of an infection on a population of size N, which remains constant.

Let H(t) be the number of healthy people at time t, a simple model for this, is given by the equation

$ \frac{\partial H}{\partial t} = -kH(N-H) $

Which is a non-linear ODE, which can be easily solved by separation of variables, and solves to

$ H(t) = N \frac{e^{cN-kNt}}{e^{cN-kNt}-1} $.

I'm interested in the fixed points of the ODE and their stability.

$ \frac{\partial H}{\partial t} = 0 \iff H(t) = 0 \  or \  H(t) = N $

Which means there are only two fixed points, which are either when the population is fully healthy (H(t)=N) or the population is fully infected (H(t)=0).

Is this procedure to find fixed points correct?

How can I work out which of these fixed points is the stable one and which one is the unstable one?

Comment: Yes, these are the steady states/equilibriums/stationary points, and if you want, the fixed points. I find it somewhat far-fetched to associate the logistic growth model with virus infections, even the "zombie apocalypse" model is usually too simple.

Comment: How do I figure out which of the fixed points is stable or unstable? By what you see I guess everyone ends up infected so H(t)=0 is the stable one, how do I prove this?

Comment: By looking at the linearization. The solution per matrix exponential is in most cases similar to the solution of the original system, see Grobman-Hartman theorem. But here you also have a solution formula where you can directly compute the limits.